# Why is OpenMP reduction failing with error message 'user defined reduction not found for 'avgs'?'

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, reduce

Why is the reduction in this code throwing an error:

```
user defined reduction not found for 'avgs'
```

---

```
void parallel_avg_pixel(long img[DIM_ROW][DIM_COL][DIM_RGB], long *avgs) {
    int row, col, pixel;
    long count = 0;

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:avgs)
    for (row = 0; row < DIM_ROW; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < DIM_COL; col++) {
            for (pixel = 0; pixel < DIM_RGB; pixel++){
                avgs[pixel] += img[row][col][pixel];
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    count /= 3;

    for (pixel = 0; pixel < DIM_RGB; pixel++) {
        avgs[pixel] /= count;
    }
}
```

I expected this code to make the value of `avgs` private for each thread in parallel and then sum them all together at the end of execution of the for loops.

Comment: Would you mind giving some feedback on the answer below? Did it solve your problem? If yes, please mark it as "accepted"'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `avgs` is a pointer. You can not reduce on pointers. OpenMP is telling you that if you want to reduce pointers, you need to define a reduction for them.

Ok, you're using it as an array but then the problem is OpenMP doesn't know how long it is.

Use the following syntax:

```
#pragma omp reduction(+:avgs[0:DIM_RGB])
```